# How do I put a double-faced card in my deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards, mtg-meld

I was reading recently about double-faced cards. Basically, they are cards that are otherwise typical creature cards, but some condition allows you to flip them over so that they become a new card.

[*Meld* cards](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/latest-developments/stop-world-and-meld-you-2016-07-08), introduced in the *Eldritch Moon* set, are one fairly noteworthy example. For instance, this

[image: Gisela, the Broken Blade][image: Bruna, the Fading Light]

Becomes this when you flip them over

[image: Brisela, Voice of Nightmares, top][image: Brisela, Voice of Nightmares, bottom]

How do you actually put double-faced cards like this in your deck, given that they do not have *Magic: The Gathering* card backs? Is it only playable with sleeves (requiring you to pull it out and flip it over)? Or is there some other aspect that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I've moved an old discussion of whether this was a duplicate [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74819/discussion-on-question-by-thunderforge-how-do-i-put-a-double-faced-card-in-my-de).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use card sleeves, as you suggested, or use checklist cards, which were included in booster packs of Eldritch Moon. These checklist cards are single faced, and included a list of all of the double faced cards in the set. I've also seen people write on basic lands to note the card (though this isn't allowed in tournaments).

[image: checklist card]

Answer (score 14):

You can use opaque sleeves, or a "checklist" card that is included in the promo slot of packs that may contain transforming cards. These checklist cards have a normal Magic back.

> 711.3. Players must ensure that double-faced cards in hidden zones are indistinguishable from other cards in the same zone. To do this, the
>   owner of a double-faced card may use completely opaque card sleeves or
>   substitute a checklist card (see rule 713).
>
> 713. Checklist Cards
>
> 713.1. A checklist card is a game supplement that can be used to represent a double-faced card or meld card.
>
> 713.2. A checklist card has a normal Magic card back. The face of a checklist card is divided into sections. Each section lists the name
>   and mana cost of each double-faced card or meld card it could
>   represent and includes a fill-in circle. Before a checklist card can
>   be used, exactly one of the fill-in circles must be marked to denote
>   which card the checklist card represents.
>
> 713.3. If a checklist card is used in a deck, the card it represents is set aside prior to the beginning of the game (see rule 103.1a) and
>   must remain available throughout the game. A checklist card can’t be
>   included in a deck unless it is representing a double-faced card or a
>   meld card.
>
> 713.4. For all game purposes, the checklist card is considered to be the card it’s representing.
>
> 713.5. If the checklist card is face up in a public zone, it should be set aside and the double-faced card or meld card that it represents
>   should be used instead.

Comment: So I can draw my DFC into my hand, but when I play it, I should replace it with the actual DFC? Or do I only do so when I flip it?

Comment: Do you mean “draw Checklist Card into hand”? When the Checklist card is played it is replaced with the actual DFC. Most people put the DFC into a completely clear sleeve.

Comment: If you want to use the real DFC in your deck with opaque-backed sleeves, you’ll either need to reverse it in the sleeve to flip it or have another copy to show the back side of.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on how many double sided cards you have in your deck it may get expensive or difficult to get your hands on enough of the checklist cards. For the custom werewolf commander deck I built I had around sixty or so cards that were double sided. Since i do not play in tournaments or anything I had the idea to try a dealer shoe. This worked out great. I did angle the shoe away from me so that no one could see the top card, but this allowed me to keep the cards all in the same clear sleeves, together, organized, and easy to play. The one thing I might try to do differently is to not buy one as large as I did. I think a three or four deck shoe would work... This is the one I purchased:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FSSQRG/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o07_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FSSQRG)

Comment: Would this be allowed in tournaments?

Comment: [The rule quoted in this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/39292/15436) makes it clear that cards in hidden zones should be indistinguishable. DFC in clear sleeves are obviously not indistinguishable when held in the hand.

Comment: This would also be difficult to shuffle unaided by tools or other people, and without one of the players knowing information about the state of the deck as it's being shuffled (such as where various DFCs wind up), which would also make it inadmissible to tournaments.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Using this would definitely not be allowed in tournaments; but you do not have to continue pulling cards out of sleeves to flip them or purchase the checklist cards. At card kingdom the checklist cards are going for 15 cents a pop all by themselves. For my deck I have about sixty cards or so that are doublesided for my werewolf theme. That would add about ten bucks to the deck's cost which I spent about $120 or so on. It is cardboard crack enough so I try to save where I can.

Comment: @Thunderforge - This would not work in tournaments like I said, but this works perfect in my group. They shuffle fine, I'm not sure what doppelgreener is talking about. The cards go in and out very easily. And while it is possible to see the cards in other zones I use clear matte sleeves which are a great balance between hiding the card and seeing what it is when played.

Comment: Okay that works for while the cards are in the deck, but what about when you draw them? With 3/5 of your deck double faced, clear sleeves will mean your opponents know on average 60% of your hand from seeing the back.